# I can only compile tex files in my Dropbox directory

Tags: miktex, compiling, dropbox

As the title says, when I try to compile a simple tex file located in my Dropbox directory, everything works fine and a pdf is produced. When I try to compile the same tex file anywhere else, I get the following error :

```
I can't write on file `questionnaire2.pdf'. \end{document}
```

the file "questionnaire2.tex" is :

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

I am compiling using MiKTeX 4.5.

Edit : I am also making sure that no pdf reader is open while I try to compile.

Comment: Have you this PDF opened during compilation?

Comment: either another program (eg acrobat) is locking the file or you do not have write permissions in the folder in which pdftex is running (which is not necessarily the folder with your document)

Comment: Which pdf viewer are you using?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke No it is not opened.

Comment: @Bernard I use no pdf viewer since no pdf is built. Usually, I use the TexLive pdf viewer or Sumatra Pdf. I also sometimes use Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Acrobat Reader locks the .pdf, whennce the error meassage. SumatraPDF does not (and is much faster).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I made sure all pdf editors were close. I have also checked that I have write access to the document folder. I am not sure how I can check where pdftex is running...

Comment: @Bernard I get the issue even for new documents. It also does not explain why it works in my Dropbox folder but not anywhere else.

Comment: does it write a log file (ie can it write any files or is it just the pdf that is locked?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes it does. Reading it does not provide additional insight (I get the same "I can't write on file 'questionnaire2.pdf'" message).